# Moving WordPress page to a new domain

Tags: migration, domain

I just bought a new domain for my website and wondered how to move my existing WordPress website from one domain to another. I have found [an article](https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005585969-Move-your-WordPress-site-to-another-domain#step-2) and followed the steps there, but it didn't work very well.

So now my question is: the article says I need to change the database login data in `wp-config` and the URL to my new domain in the database. Do I need to make any other changes (e.g., the login data for my new WordPress)?

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach will be to:

- Install "**[All in one WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)**" plugin on your old domain & export the whole website using it.
- Install WordPress on your new Domain.
- Install the All in one WP Migration plugin on that domain as well & import your website using the file you downloaded.

I think this is the safest way that can be done.

[Contact me](http://fiverr.com/wpcoderpro) if you still have migration problems.

Answer (score 0):

Manual moving your files, there is a couple of steps you need to do.

1. Login on current ftp. Download wordpress install. 
   Change database settings in config.php to new database settings.
2. Login on current database, export it. Then open sql file search for current domain replace all with new domainname.
3. Login on new domain ftp. Upload wordpress install.
4. Login to new database and import de sql.

Check out your website on the new domainname.

That should be it.

Sometimes you need tot login on your wordpress dashboard en set permalinks to standard and back to your required settings, if plugin or pages don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin called [Duplicator](https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) which creates a package containing your whole website and its database. After this you can download this package and upload it to the website with new domain name.

Complete step by step is on [their official website](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/?utm_source=duplicator_free&utm_medium=wp_org&utm_content=desc_details&utm_campaign=duplicator_free). For simple migration, you should be completely OK with the free version of this plugin.

Comment: Except make sure Duplicator is the latest version. Earlier versions have a problem with exposure of your database credentials, lots of hackers looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

WP Clone is the easiest and best way out to do seamlessly website transfer.

Install this plugin, generate a backup, copy that back URL.
Install a fresh WordPress on new domain, install this plugin, go to restore backup option, put copied backup URL into this field and boom, everything will be transferred seamlessly.

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried lots of the 'moving' plugins, and they don't always work well, or the complete process requires getting the premium ($$) version.

So I developed my own process, which, although not automatic and takes some time/effort, works each time I have done it.

It's a manual 'clone' process, and is too long for an answer here. I wrote about it - mostly as a place to keep the process handy for the next time I use it. See https://securitydawg.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/ .

Again, a bit of work to do it. But the process has worked fine for me each time I need to do it.